# The 'blur' event is triggerd but the 'save' event is not when the element is out of focus

Tags: javascript, events

For a field in form that's mandatory, there is a `blur` event which is triggered every time the element is out of focus.

Within the same form, there is a `save` event which should be triggered when the 'save' button is clicked. But the `blur` event is triggered first and then the 'save' button needs to be clicked again tos the form.
Is there a way I can stop triggering the `blur` event  to fire when the 'save' button is clicked?

Comment: Is the `blur` event on the "save" button?

Comment: No, it is on the form element , to validate if the value is entered or not